# How to add data to generic array list in java

Tags: java, android

I am very new in java reflection and generic types. I am now developing database handler library for android. I am stuck at returning array list from reflection.

for example:

This class is the library user's class

```
public class Creation extends SimpleDBHandler<Creation> {

private String tools;
private String nature;

public Creation(String tools,String nature) {

this.tools = tools;
this.nature = nature;

}

public String getTools() {
    return tools;
}
public void setTools(String tools) {
    this.tools = tools;

}
public String getNature() {
    return nature;
}
public void setNature(String nature) {
    this.nature = nature;
}

}
```

This class is the library user class

usage:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
ArrayList<Creation> arrList = new ArrayList<>();

arrList = new SimpleDBHandler<Creation>().getAllData(Creation.class);
}
}
```

This is library class

```
public class SimpleDBHandler<T> {


public <T extends SimpleDBHandler<?>> ArrayList<T> getAllData(Class<?> mClass) {

ArrayList<T> arrList = new ArrayList<>();


// I am suck here. How to add data to arrList?

return arrList;
}

}
```

Please help me. Thanks before.

Comment: Nevermind, this isn't a reflection question, it's generics

Comment: If you want a list which you can insert `T` into, you'd need a `List<? super T>`, but keep in mind you still need ton be able to retrieve `T` values, which is the harder part. And half the reason you even use a database is so you _don't_ have to load all of your data into the application.

Comment: Yes,@Rogue. Can you explain me more detail with example. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried to retrieve from the database so far? Are you using JDBC?

Comment: Actually, retrieve from the database is not a problem. The problem is to add the data to the array list.

Comment: Well, a `List<? super T>` can be added to. You need to create a relevant `T` from your database info (in this case, a Creation object), and then add it to the list. You could potentially do something like `public abstract SimpleDBHandler<T> create(ResultSet in);` which would allow subclasses of SimpleDBHandler to create themselves from the ResultSet, and then you simply add the return value to the list.

Comment: Thank @Rogue. I think I am close. But I will appreciate if you explain me with sample code. Thank again.